# Error populating transaction after 10 anaconda retries: failure: <RPM> from anaconda: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try

Tags: linux, installation, anaconda

I'm running into the following package error on CentOS 7 installation while customizing an ISO for automated installs.

```
packaging.log:03:52:50,495 ERR packaging:  Error populating transaction after 10 anaconda retries: failure: perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch.rpm from anaconda: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I've verified the above package is in the Packages/ directory.  Verified that the package appears in the comps.xml and .xml files within the repodata/ folder .gz files.

Createrepo command is:

```
[root@server01 Packages]# createrepo -dpo .. . -g /server-images/working/repodata/521f322f05f9802f2438d8bb7d97558c64ff3ff74c03322d77787ade9152d8bb-c7-x86_64-comps.xml
```

What could be the issue or what could I check next?  I'm not able to find much on the web.

Thx,

---

```
03:44:17,600 DEBUG yum.verbose.YumBase: TSINFO: Marking ruby-irb-2.0.0.648-36.el7.noarch as install for rubygem-rdoc-4.0.0-36.el7.noarch
03:44:17,616 DEBUG yum.verbose.YumBase: TSINFO: Marking 1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch as install for perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
03:44:17,618 DEBUG yum.verbose.YumBase: TSINFO: Marking perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch as install for perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
03:44:17,738 DEBUG yum.verbose.YumBase: Depsolve time: 2.066
03:44:17,749 INFO packaging: 373 packages selected totalling 1566.61 MiB
03:44:17,799 INFO packaging: Running anaconda-yum to install packages
03:44:18,737 INFO packaging:  populate transaction set
03:52:50,495 ERR packaging:  Error populating transaction after 10 anaconda retries: failure: perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch.rpm from anaconda: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I've tried the solution on this page but adding `-untranslated-filename` had no effect:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232155/centos-7-install-error-populating-transaction

Anaconda keeps trying to look for packages under file:///run/install/repo rather then file:///run/install/repo/Packages/ where packages reside.

Leaning towards my createrepo command rather than anything else as the culprit but just can't pinpoint the specific syntax I might be needing.

Answer (score 2):

When you generate your repo, prior to generating the ISO, make sure you are in your working root and do NOT specify ./Packages as an argument to `createrepo`:

```
createrepo -dpo . ./ -g ...etc...
```

and NOT

```
createrepo -dpo . ./Packages -g ...etc...
```

Source: https://microdevsys.com/wp/errno-256-no-more-mirrors-to-try/